# Yii Bootster - TbTabs Change Tab Event

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-booster

How can I control a change of tab event when using TbTabs in Yii Bootter?

Here is my code (but it didn't alert when I have changed tab):

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'type' => 'tabs',
        'tabs' => array(
            array('label' => 'Trainer Modules', 'content' => 'content tab 1',
            array('label' => 'Default Modules', 'content' => 'content tab 2',
        ),
        'events' => array(
            'change' => "js:function(){alert('123');}"
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Which version of `yii-booster TbTabs` you are using?

Comment: In TbTabs; `run` method, you have code which will register your events handlers for the component.
So if it does not work for you, can you check whether it gives Javascript error in console or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the future reference, one solution to control Tab clicks on TbTabs is to assign Id to each tab and handle the event using ClientScript, Here is how it works:

Assign id to each link like this:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'type'=>'tabs',
    'placement'=>'above', // 'above', 'right', 'below' or 'left'
    'tabs'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Section 1', 'active'=>true, 'linkOptions' => array('id'=>'link1')),
        array('label'=>'Section 2', 'linkOptions' => array('id'=>'link2')),
    ),
));
```

Then register your js using CClientScript

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("link1Click", "$('#link1').click(function(){alert('link1 is clicked');})");
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("link1Click", "$('#link2').click(function(){alert('link2 is clicked');})");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tabs are `ul` and `li` element. They don't have `change` event.

see the code:

```
foreach ($this->events as $name => $handler)
    {
        $handler = CJavaScript::encode($handler);
        $cs->registerScript(__CLASS__.'#'.$id.'_'.$name, "jQuery('#{$id}').on('{$name}', {$handler});");
    }
```

it similar: `$('ul').on('change', function () { alert('123'); });` => not work.

Comment: Ok! Thanks you so much! I have not yet read the code.
But I have just found a solution! That is every tabs has a content with id. So on event 'show', we just check the tab which is active... ^_^

Answer (score 0):

`TbTab` is working fine but there is no `change` event for `Bootstrap Tab`.

You can find `Bootstrap Tab` js documentation (applicable events) [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp):

So your code needs a little change to work:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
        'type' => 'tabs',
        'tabs' => array(
            array('label' => 'Trainer Modules', 'content' => 'content tab 1',
            array('label' => 'Default Modules', 'content' => 'content tab 2',
        ),
        'events' => array(
            'show.bs.tab' => "js:function(tab){console.log(tab); alert(tab);}" // Occurs when the tab is about to be shown.
            'shown.bs.tab' => "js:function(tab){console.log(tab); alert(tab);}" // Occurs when the tab is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed)
        )
    ));
```

Real credit should go to [Another Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change)